# User-friendly way of dividing a value in three

Tags: widget

Obviously a slider is ideal for separating a value in 2, but what if we need to separate a value in three?
Does anyone know of a user-friendly way to achieve this?
Right now I'm using two sliders which reference (and move) each other, but it isn't very intuitive, is it?

Best regards

Comment: I have found the dual-thumb slider. I suppose it's the most intuitive widget for that usage scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised I didn't get any answers, as it seems quite a few people have wanted this widget before me.
Anyways, a slider with two thumbs is the solution everyone (and I) settled on.